# Overloading Operator == C++

Tags: c++

The code for my question can be located at http://matthewh.me/Scripts/c++/graphs/. The user name is guest password is guest. This will give you read access to the svn repository. I do this to save your eyes while reading this post.

Now to my question, which is with regards to overloading the == operator on a class. The code I have does not seem to be working but according to how I am interpreting it, it should (I need to be more humble and accept what the compiler says). Below is the portion of the code that is not working, as long as the chain of code segments that lead to it.

```
template<typename S,typename T>
template<typename U,typename V>
bool Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::operator== ( Node<S,T> *comp ) {
    cout  << "Searching for";
    comp->print_self( );
    bool ret = false;
    if( this->key == comp->key && this->value == comp->value ) {
        ret = true;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

This is used when building a graph to make sure I don't insert duplicate Nodes. The Node and graph classes can be found in the code in the repository. To continue is the chain of blocks that lead to where this would be called.

First my driver:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
    Graph<int, int> graph;
    pair<int,int> p1(3,4);
    pair<int,int> p2(3,4);

    graph.insert_adjacents( &p1,&p2 );

    graph.print_graph( );

    //graph.print_nodes( );
}
```

The insert function (There is a memory leak here not a concern atm):

```
template<typename S,typename T>
void Graph<S,T>::insert_adjacents( pair<S,T> *from, pair<S,T> *to ) {
Node<S,T> *from_node = new Node<S,T>( from->first, from->second );
Node<S,T> *to_node = new Node<S,T>( to->first, to->second );

Node<S,T> *from_tmp = this->contains_already( from_node );
Node<S,T> *to_tmp = this->contains_already( to_node );

if( from_tmp==NULL ) {
    this->nodes.push_back( from_node );
    from_tmp = from_node;
}
if( to_tmp==NULL ) {
    this->nodes.push_back( to_node );
    to_tmp = to_node;
}

Node<S,T> *from_edge = from_tmp->contains_adjacent_node( to_tmp );
Node<S,T> *to_edge = to_tmp->contains_adjacent_node( from_tmp );

if( from_edge==NULL ) {
    from_tmp->insert_adjacent_node( to_node,rand( )%20 );
}
if( to_edge==NULL ) {
    to_tmp->insert_adjacent_node( from_node,rand( )%20 );
}
```

}

Now the contains functions for both Graph and Node are:

```
template<typename S,typename T>
Graph<S,T>::Node<S,T>* Graph<S,T>::contains_already( Node<S,T> *check ) {
    cout << "Searching for Node ";
    check->print_self( );
    cout << " in node list" << endl;
        typename list<Node<S,T>* >::iterator start = nodes.begin( );
        typename list<Node<S,T>* >::iterator end = nodes.end( );
        while( start != end ) {
                if( *(start) == check ) {
            cout << "Found ";
            (*start)->print_self( );
            cout << endl;
                        return (*start);
                }
                start++;
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

and

```
template<typename S,typename T>
template<typename U,typename V>
Graph<S,T>::Node<S,T>* Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::contains_adjacent_node( Node<S,T> *adj ) {
    cout << "Checking for adjacent node ";
    adj->print_self( );
    cout << " next to ";
    this->print_self( );
    cout << endl;
    typename list<Edge*>::iterator start = adj->adjacents.begin( );
    typename list<Edge*>::iterator end = adj->adjacents.end( );
    while( start != end ) {
        if( (*start)->adjacent == adj ) {
            return (*start)->adjacent;
        }
        start++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Which both use the == operator to compare if two nodes are identical. Do I need to deference the pointers to make this work?

I know there are quite a few knowledgeable people out there, please help a younger C++ developer learn the ways.

Thank you,
Matthew Hoggan

---

UPDATE

I couldn't resist and the wife is being a bit slow, so I decided to try and fix it before we left. Anyways, the two pieces of code updated are as follows, but they still don't seem to be working. Any help now at this point is greatly appreciated.

```
template<typename S,typename T>
template<typename U,typename V>
bool Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::operator== ( Node<S,T> &comp ) const {
        cout  << "Searching for";
        comp.print_self( );
        bool ret = false;
        if( this->key == comp.key && this->value == comp.value ) {
                ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
}
```

and

```
template<typename S,typename T>
template<typename U,typename V>
Graph<S,T>::Node<S,T>* Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::contains_adjacent_node( Node<S,T> *adj ) {
        cout << "Checking for adjacent node ";
        adj->print_self( );
        cout << " next to ";
        this->print_self( );
        cout << endl;
        typename list<Edge*>::iterator start = adj->adjacents.begin( );
        typename list<Edge*>::iterator end = adj->adjacents.end( );
        while( start != end ) {
                if( (*(*start)->adjacent) == (*adj) ) {
                        return (*start)->adjacent;
                }
                start++;
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

and

```
template<typename S,typename T>
Graph<S,T>::Node<S,T>* Graph<S,T>::contains_already( Node<S,T> *check ) {
        cout << "Searching for Node ";
        check->print_self( );
        cout << " in node list" << endl;
        typename list<Node<S,T>* >::iterator start = nodes.begin( );
        typename list<Node<S,T>* >::iterator end = nodes.end( );
        while( start != end ) {
                if( (*(*(start))) == (*check) ) {
                        cout << "Found ";
                        (*start)->print_self( );
                        cout << endl;
                        return (*start);
                }
                start++;
        }
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: since it's occurred to you to dereference the pointers, why not do so and see what happens? Then you can ask why it's that way, if it's not obvious to you after the fact.

Comment: It would help to know what does "don't seem to be working" mean. Maybe it's working but not doing what you might have expected? Why not give an example of what the data is, what you expect the code to do and what in reality happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you should dereference the pointers.

In this code:

```
(*start)->adjacent == adj
```

(Assuming both `adjacent` and `adj` are pointers to your class objects) you're comparing pointers, your operator is not invoked at all.

BTW: I always thought you're supposed to [pass reference](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) to the `operator==`, i.e.: it should be:

```
bool Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::operator== (const Node<S,T> &comp ) const
```

Instead of what you have.

Comment: To be pedantic, comparison operator should be: `bool Graph<S,T>::Node<U,V>::operator==(const Node<S,T>& comp) const` -- that is be a const method that takes a const reference.

Comment: I will attempt to change that later this after noon. That sounds about right, but I want to confirm before marking this as the answer. Taking the wife to the hospital in an hour and have to start getting things ready.

Comment: @Chad - you meant comparison operator, assignment shouldn't be `const` :-) Yes, you're right, but that's not the issue at hand.

Comment: @littleadv -- you're right on both accounts.  Just wanted to clarify what `operator==`'s  "generally accepted" signature.